# Jython, Jepp or Pylons for the performance

Tags: python, performance, pylons, jython

I'm trying to incorporate server-based code diff and highlighting in my GWT (Java) project. I managed to incorporate Pygments and difflib [into my code using Jython](http://dev.bostone.us/2010/12/01/python-pygments-in-java-with-jython/#awp%3a:2010/12/01/python-pygments-in-java-with-jython/). The basic idea is to generate complete markup on the server and then simply inject code into the page as `innerHTML`. 
I found Jython completely inadequate as even for relatively small files (2K-3K lines) it takes Pygments or difflib forever (minutes not seconds) to process these files. Difflib actually reliably causes OOM errors in the process with dedicated 500M of memory
So I'm wondering if [my current setup](http://dev.bostone.us/2010/12/01/python-pygments-in-java-with-jython/#awp%3a:2010/12/01/python-pygments-in-java-with-jython/) is wrong or Jython is simply unsuitable for this purpose?

If so, what's next? I discover [Jepp](http://jepp.sourceforge.net/) but then I would have to build my project for each platform and it has little documentation and don't seem very stable. Another possibility would be to run Pylons as a separate webservice on the same host and get the markup directly to client or channel it through server. And yet another way is to use Java System to execute python script as a process and capture the output.

I would be very interested to hear solid suggestion on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a separate service sounds like the best way to go. For Pygments, there is already a service [available](http://pygments.appspot.com/)  (on Google App Engine). The source for the app is BSD open source and on GitHub [here](http://github.con/trevorturk/pygments/). You could adapt this to add difflib functionality too, of course.

Comment: Yeah. I just discovered "bottle" (http://bottle.paws.de) and I think it will solve all my troubles :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept answer above since it coincides with my findings but just to let anyone who reads this know - running separate webservice for Pygments using Python-native solution such as Bottle performs many times better than embedded Jython. Especially on Linux